# RAID0, LVM or JBOD for best performance squid proxy server?

Tags: centos, proxy, squid, linux, transparent-proxy

I need to choise the storage type for a squid proxy server with 100Mb/s traffic.

RAID0, LVM or JBOD

Which is better for performance (don't care the data reliability) ?

This storage is only for the squid cache (not system disk).

I have 3 disk for the array.

I'm using centos 5

Comment: Have your read the entry in the [Squid FAQ](http://wiki.squid-cache.org/SquidFaq/RAID)

Comment: Documentation's a fad.  It'll never catch on.

Answer (score 0):

JBOD is the fastest. You can even get a better performance with SSD hard disks.

Not seriously:
And if you don't relay on reliability then what about ramdisks? You can't beat their performance.

Comment: Thanks, do you know where I found a guide for JBOD configure ? I can't found anything.

Comment: JBOD means "just a bunch". So just _use_ them. Probably as Zoredache suggests or as MikeyB suggests. Nothing special.

Comment: @Roberto: The faaaaq... [the faaaaaaaaaaaaq...](http://wiki.squid-cache.org/SquidFaq/RAID)

Comment: To configure squid with jbod.  Install disks, setup one [cache_dir](http://www.squid-cache.org/Doc/config/cache_dir/) per disk.

Answer (score 0):

Your fastest option will probably be three separate mountpoints, one for each disk. Configure Squid to balance across them.